# Shell script auto provide input for command

Tags: macos, shell

I am building an auto build script for generating applications. Before I ran every command manually. The build script is almost finished, but there is a problem. Some commands require input, but I don't know how to provide input to the commands without prompting the user. For example:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore Keystore/$name.keystore -alias $lowername -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

This asks for the current password which is always the same, but I need to enter this every time.

Is there a way I can provide the answers to the questions I get when running the command without showing this to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the program **expect** (part of a TCL extension library)  to achieve this.
It is pretty trivial to use.

Comment: This appeared to be the one I looked for, but I can't seem to get it working. I tried creating a separate script, but it seems I need the spawn command, which is not installed and I don't have the permission to do this.